# How to interact with submit input type with no name in php using curl?

Tags: php, html, curl

```
<select name="_limit">
<option value='50'  >50</option>
<option value='200'  >200</option>
<option value='300'  >300</option>
<option value='500'  >500</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-success"/>
```

Here, the page displays list containing 50 data by default. I want to change the display limit to higher value like 200.

How can it be done using curl?

Note: The list is filtered only when the 'Filter' submit button is clicked.

For select option I can use something like

```
$post_str = "_limit=200";
```

But what about the submit input type as there is no name?

Comment: What happens on submit? Is it another method call or ajax? Your requirement is not clear for anybody to help you. Be specific and clear.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any other method call or ajax involved. But this form, action="same url". The specific site is http://www.nepalstock.com/todaysprice       You can check it out